# Music is not resuming from where it was closed

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Please check my code .My music restarts instead of resuming from where
 it was left.Also please give the solution to this.
My requirement:The music should pause when the home button is pressed and it should start again from where it closed on opening it from recent acticvity list.

```
 package com.example.android.mediaplayerdemonstration;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (mySound != null)
                mySound.pause();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if(mySound != null)
                mySound.start();
        }


        MediaPlayer mySound;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mySound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.sleep);
            mySound.start();
            mySound.setLooping(true);

        }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll put this in an answer. There's nothing wrong with your code, runs fine for me. 
Try overriding `onStop()` to check if it's being called when you're pressing the home button or at some other time.

```
@override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.v("test", "stopped");
}
```

`onStop()`is called if a higher priority app needs the memory. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle.

If you really need the app to always remember when the `MediaPlayer` was paused maybe save it in a file or in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Is the music resuming from where it was left ,when you tried?

Comment: Yes, it resumes from when it was paused.